# Docker-machine access to remote docker daemon through ssh tunneling

Tags: docker, docker-machine, ssh-tunnel

I want to use docker machine with a remote server docker daemon through ssh so no need to open 2376 port in the remote server.

**Local Host:**

> $ docker-machine create --driver generic  --generic-ip-address
> [IP_Address] --generic-engine-port 2376 --generic-ssh-key
> ~/.ssh/id_rsa --generic-ssh-user root [Host]

**Remote host:**

> $ docker daemon -H tcp://127.0.0.1:2376

**Result of executing the Local Host command:**

> $ docker-machine create --driver generic --generic-ip-address
> [IP_Address] --generic-engine-port 2376 --generic-ssh-key
> ~/.ssh/id_rsa --generic-ssh-user root [Host]
>
> ...
>
> *Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?*

As per nmap remote port 2376 is closed, so the error makes sense.

I have tried tunneling through ssh by executing the following in my local host:

> $ ssh -L 2376:127.0.0.1:2376 [Remote_Host]

** Note docker machine is trying to reach docker daemon in the remote host, so the tunnel is useful **

I thought maybe using ssh -R or a combination of both would work but I have not been able to make it work yet, do you have any idea or workaround to make this work?

Do not hesitate to bring me to a completely different approach to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is SSH service running on the remote machine that you are trying to connect to?

Comment: yes, is it running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [rdocker](https://github.com/dvddarias/rdocker)? It seems to do exactly what you are looking for. Cheers

Comment: Nice!!, it does exactly what I need. Thx